# jquery add a row after the first row

Tags: jquery, html

I have my html markup like this

```
<table class="left-column-form" id="ref-table">
                    <tr>
                        <th style="width:20%">Shipping Service Name</th>
                    <th style="width:20%">From Price</th>
                        <th style="width:20%">To Price</th>
                        <th style="width:20%">Price</th>
                        <th style="width:20%">Additional Price</th>
                    </tr>
          <tr id="row">
                        <td style="width:20%;">
                        <select name="">
                            <option value="" selected>--Select-- </option>
                            <option value="service-one">Service One </option>
                            <option value="service-two">Service Two </option>
                            <option value="service-three">Service Three </option>
                        </select>
                        </td>
                        <td style="width:20%;">
                            <input type="text" name="from-price"/>
                        </td>
                        <td style="width:20%;">
                            <input type="text" name="to-price"/>
                        </td>
                        <td style="width:20%;">
                            <input type="text" name="price"/>
                        </td>
                        <td style="width:20%;">
                            <input type="text" name="additional-price"/>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
```

under that I have one button like this

```
<input type="submit" id="add-services" value="Add Service" />
```

I want that when someone will click on the button it will add another row like

```
<tr id="row">
                    <td style="width:20%;">
                    <select name="">
                        <option value="" selected>--Select-- </option>
                        <option value="service-one">Service One </option>
                        <option value="service-two">Service Two </option>
                        <option value="service-three">Service Three </option>
                    </select>
                    </td>
                    <td style="width:20%;">
                        <input type="text" name="from-price"/>
                    </td>
                    <td style="width:20%;">
                        <input type="text" name="to-price"/>
                    </td>
                    <td style="width:20%;">
                        <input type="text" name="price"/>
                    </td>
                    <td style="width:20%;">
                        <input type="text" name="additional-price"/>
                    </td>
                </tr>
```

just after the first row. So can someone tell me how to do this in a good coding manner?

Comment: And you tried what so far?

Comment: Except for making sure that the IDs are different, this seems completely trivial. That caveat just turns it from trivial to easy.

Comment: In a good coding manner use php. To be able to make a more suitable suggestion please state what do you hope to achieve, why and what have you tried?

Comment: @otherDewi what makes php good coding manner for this? can copy these rows with just a few lines of jQuery. Its a UI, pretty normal concept duplicating rows

Answer (score 1):

Change your ID's on rows to class since ID's must be unique:

On page load can copy a row and store it:

```
var $row=$('tr.row:first').clone();    
/* add a copy back in table*/
$('#add-services').click(function(){
  $('tr:first').after( $row.clone());
});
```

If need to clear input values of iniital clone add:

```
$row.find('input').val('')
```

Answer (score 1):

Two things:

## Semantics - use `<tbody>` and `<thead>`

You can write your table like this:

```
<table id="ref-table">
  <thead><tr><td colspan="5"><select name="..">...</select></td></tr></thead>
  <tbody><tr><td><input type="text" name="from-price"/></td>...</tr></tbody>
</table>
```

## Using `.clone()`:

Once you've done that, you can easily make use of jQuery's [`clone`](http://api.jquery.com/clone/) call.

You can always do something like this:

```
function copyMe() {
  return $(this).clone().insertAfter(this).first();
}

var newRow = $('#ref-table tbody tr:first-child').map(copyMe)[0]
```

Then you can use `newRow` however you wish to, replace the cloned input's values with new/default ones. You can customise `first-child` into `last-child` (think of user experience).

The big benefit is that you need not have to embed any HTML into your JavaScript. You can even hide the first row with CSS and use it as a template and nothing more. You might want to also look at `insertBefore`.

Answer (score 0):

You could try this:

```
$("#myButton").click(function(){
    $("#ref-table tr:first").after("<tr><td class='myTd'>content2</td><td  class='myTd'>content2</td></tr>");
});
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/T88k7/4/

Answer (score 0):

It seems the desired behavior is to add the row after first row and not after the header row and below is the code (tested) that does it.

```
$(function () {
    var rowNo = 0;

    $("#add-services").click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var rowHtml = '<tr id="row'+(rowNo++)+'"><td>'+$('select[name="service-name"]').val()+'</td><td>'+$('input[name="from-price"]').val()+'</td><td>'+$('input[name="to-price"]').val()+'</td><td>'+$('input[name="price"]').val()+'</td><td>'+$('input[name="additional-price"]').val()+'</td></tr>';
        $('#ref-table > tbody > tr').eq(1).after(rowHtml);
    });
});
```

Also, it seems that you missed to add the name to the select box. Please replace

```
<select name="">
```

with

```
<select name="service-name">
```